# No puedo guardar los datos en una base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando guardar datos de un formulario hecho en php los codigos son los siguientes.

Formulario de registro

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Formulario de registro </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Formulario de registro </h1>
    <h5> Los campos con (*) son requeridos </h5>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <table>
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    Nombre y apellidos:
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <input type="name" name="realname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    *Nick de usuario
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="name" name="nick" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    *Contraseña:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    *Repetir contraseña:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="rpass" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrarme" /> <input type="reset" />
    </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            require("registro.php");
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

archivo de php en el que se encuentra metodo post.

```
<?php
    $realname = $_POST['realname'];
    $nick = $_POST['nick'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $rpass = $_POST['rpass'];
    $reqlen   = strlen($nick) * strlen($pass) * strlen($rpass);
    if ($reqlen > 0) {
        if ($pass === $rpass) {
            require("connect_db.php");
            $pass = md5($pass);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO registro VALUES('','$realname','$nick','$pass')");
            mysql_close($link);
            echo 'Se ha registrado exitosamente.';
        } else {
            echo 'Por favor, introduzca dos contraseñas idénticas.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Por favor, rellene todos los campos requeridos.';
    }
?>
```

porque no guarda los datos en la base de datos? me pueden ayudar, mil gracias.

Comment: Ya verificaste el query de forma manual en tu Base de datos, con php el error mas comun es con las comillas simples.

Comment: A parte de lo que te han dicho en las respuestas anteriores deberías usar la extensión mysqli o PDO en vez de mysql, pues mysql se considera obsoleta

Answer (score 2):

Como dice Elenasys, falta definir el action en el form, suponiendo que tu archivo se llama registro.php, en tu caso sería:

```
<form method="POST" action="registro.php">
```

Algo adicional que veo es que en tu Query SQL no estas definiendo las columnas a las que quieres ingresar eso datos:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO registro VALUES('','$realname','$nick','$pass')");
```

Debería ser:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO registro(columna1, columna2, columna3, columna4) VALUES('','$realname','$nick','$pass')");
```

Suponiendo que tienes un campo autoincrementable donde no se necesita colocar el nombre de la columna, y donde no existan mas columnas a las que insertar datos, sino te genera un error al momento de ejecutar la consulta.

Como dato adicional no uses el **Driver mysql** para realizar la conexion a la base de datos, usa en su lugar **mysqli** o **PDO**, ya que el driver mysql quedo obsoleto en PHP 5.5 y será eliminado en PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

falta definir en la propiedad `action` el nombre de tu archivo .php :

```
<form method="POST" action="archivo.php">
```

para que puedas realizar correctamente la operación.

Dentro de tu archivo .php existe otro problema, es incorrecto tu query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO registro VALUES('','$realname','$nick','$pass')");
```

Debes definir los campos:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO registro (nombrecampo1, nombrecampo2, nombrecampo3, nombrecampo4) VALUES('','$realname','$nick','$pass')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Aun no haz definido en que campos vas a guardar los datos, mira tu codigo es asi:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO registro VALUES ('','$realname','$nick','$pass')");
```

Cuando realmente deberia ser asi, dependiendo que campos tienes en tu tabla:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO registro ('','realname','nick','pass') VALUES ('','$realname','$nick','$pass')");
```

Solo lo que no comprendo es, el por que dejas un campo vacio?